# Use regex to find which date separator a user has inputted

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex that will return characters in a string not equal to d, M or y.

For example:

in dd.MM.yyyy, I should get a ' . '

in dd/MM/yyyy, I should get a ' / '

Is this possible?

Comment: Depends how exact you want to be: ONE method would be `'22/10/2013'.match(/\d\d?(.)\d\d?\1\d\d(\d\d)?/)[1];` which returns `"/"`, but would break with `'22/10.2013'` because it expects the same delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to parse input date, find first non numeric character

```
[0-9]+([^0-9]).*
```

If you try to find element in "mask/template/..." then first character not in set

```
[dMy]+(\.).*
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will always get a string in that format and casing, then you could use `dd(.)MM(.)yyyy`. This will match the two strings above and put the seperating character in a group, which you can then later access.